# Font sizes of inline code and code blocks don't match.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I noticed the following difference in font sizes, using Firefox 3.6.12 on Windows Vista:

[image]

Is this a design decision or a bug?

Comment: What code is used to generate this?

Comment: @Charles: The usual 4 space indentation; it's a screenshot of part of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/nested-indentation-of-text-blocks/5993#5993).

Comment: I just remembered why I did this. The code appearing in the post/answer text has the same size as the rest of the body text size. The code block text is slightly smaller. I intentionally made the code block a bit smaller so it's easier to differentiate. Also this allows more text to be displayed before scrollbar appears. Do you see this as a problem?

Comment: @Jin: Thanks for your explanation. I don't see a problem for larger blocks of code, as one usually won't read them thoroughly anyway but only use them for cut and paste. (So it might indeed be helpful to have it a bit smaller.) However, if there are only 1 or 2 lines of code, then I find it harder to read with the smaller font. It would be interesting to know what others think.

Comment: I like it as it is, mainly for the reasons Jin gave.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be resolved, but for posterity's reference value, the code:

```
Your attempt with `\leftskip` didn't work because you need to end the paragraph before ending the group with `}`. The following works:

    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{1cm}This has an increased left margin.\par}
```

Your attempt with `\leftskip` didn't work because you need to end the paragraph before ending the group with `}`. The following works:

```
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1cm}This has an increased left margin.\par}
```

Comment: how is this resolved? it's exactly the same

Comment: @Jeff: resolved =/= solved (one for english.SX methinks).

Comment: @Jeff: Jin explained why it is like it is, and it seemed like a reasonable explanation. So it's still the same as before, but now we understand why it counts as a feature :-).